# Visual Studio : Error occurred while restoring nuget packages : There are duplicate packages

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

When I tried to build my Solution, I got the following error in Visual Studio 2015. `Error Occurred while restoring nuget packages..... there are duplicate packages....`. Because of this most of my assemblies in `references` shows an Yellow Triangle and is not restored.

How to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Restoring nuget packages can fail in multiple scenarios. In this particular case, it is because of `duplicate packages`. If you read the full error message you will also find what package is present as duplicate.

To resolve this, open your `packages.config` file and remove this duplicate package entry from that. Then try to `Build` or `Restore Nuget Packages`. Things should work fine.

Comment: it doesn't work for me, still get the same message(nonetheless .packages was updated)